# What if any operation can I use to check GLSL int precision matches the claimed precision?

Tags: opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I have an OpenGL ES 2.0 app that gets different results for `mediump` vs `highp`. Makes total sense.

Except that if I query

```
int range[2], precision;
glGetShaderPrecisionFormat(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, GL_HIGH_FLOAT, range, &precision);
printf("Fragment shader high precision float range: %d %d precision: %d\n", range[0], range[1], precision);
glGetShaderPrecisionFormat(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, GL_MEDIUM_FLOAT, range, &precision);
printf("Fragment shader medium precision float range: %d %d precision: %d\n", range[0], range[1], precision);
```

Both print the same thing

```
Fragment shader high precision float range: 127 127 precision: 23
Fragment shader medium precision float range: 127 127 precision: 23
```

This seems like a bug in the driver which sucks and I'll file a bug (assuming it is a bug in the driver)

For mediump float I was able to make a test.

```
int range[2], precision;
glGetShaderPrecisionFormat(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, GL_HIGH_FLOAT, range, &precision);

float value = sqrtf(powf(2.0f, precision) - 1.0f);
```

I upload that via mediump uniform to a shader as in

```
glUniform3f(vLocation, value, value, value);
```

for this shader

```
    precision mediump float;
    uniform mediump vec3 v;
    void main() {
      gl_FragColor = vec4(normalize(v) * 0.5 + 0.5, 1);
    }
```

and glReadPixels the result. The result should 0.577 which is about 146 when converted to an 8bit color so I checks for ~146

And testing it works. The device fails the test because it's reporting the wrong precision but other devices reporting the correct precision pass.

It actually took a while to find a test that failed and I'm not sure why. My original test was just

```
precision mediump float;
uniform mediump vec2 v;
void () {
  gl_FragColor = vec4(v.x / v.y);
}
```

And I'd pass in

```
float value = powf(2.0f, precision) - 1.0f;
glUniform2f(vLocation, value / 2, value);
```

My thinking was if internally it's really 16 bit mediump then v.x being 4194303 and v.y being 8388607 would produce the wrong result but it didn't. I get the driver is under no obligation to use the lowest precision anywhere but still, ... The thing that made me notice the driver bug in the first place was specular results being different so that's why I switched to use `normalize` for my test which did manifest the issue.

Anyway, now I want to do a simiar test for **mediump int** but I can't find a test that fails. You can't call `normalize` on an `ivec3` for example.

My first try was get the largest int based on reported range[1], divide by 2, 4, 8, and 16 in ints. upload to shader via uniform, in the shader multiply by 2, 4, 8, 16. The result of each should be the value divided value * 2, 4, 8, 16. If the driver is reporting the wrong `range[1]` for mediump (which it is, it's reporting 31 but I know it's 15) then it should overflow and get the wrong result.

```
    precision mediump float;
    uniform mediump ivec4 v;
    uniform mediump ivec4 expected;

    ivec4 iabs(ivec4 v) {
      return ivec4(
        v.x < 0 ? -v.x : v.x,
        v.y < 0 ? -v.y : v.y,
        v.z < 0 ? -v.z : v.z,
        v.w < 0 ? -v.w : v.w);
    }

    void main() {
      mediump ivec4 t = ivec4(2, 4, 8, 16);
      mediump ivec4 m = v * t;
      mediump ivec4 diff = iabs(m - expected);
      mediump ivec4 maxDiff = ivec4(4);
      bvec4 pass = lessThan(diff, maxDiff);
      gl_FragColor = pass;
    }
```

But it's passing even though I happen to know the GPU only uses 16 bits for mediump and these are the values being passed in to the test because the rangeMax being wrong from the driver

```
v = 536870910, 268435454, 134217726, 67108862
expected = 1073741820, 1073741816, 1073741808, 1073741792
```

Any idea what other test I can use to verify the actual precision of mediump int >= the reported precision of mediump int?

Comment: I haven't really tried it, but wouldn't simply using a uniform `int v` initialized with `2<<(range[1]-1)` fail the test  `v != 0` if the implementation would have a lower than advertised range?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. I pass in `uniform int v;` where v = `2<<(range[1] - 1)` but then compare it to what? a hard coded value in the shader? integer overflow is not defined in OpenGL ES 2.0 and ints can really be floats

Comment: there is no overflow in my formula (and the formula was even supposed to be done on CPU side, but it could also be moved to the dahder). and yes, compare against a hard-coded value `0`.

Comment: If I understand correctly you're assuming that the value will be out of range. As in `2<<(range[1] -1])` will produce 0x8000000 for a 31 but mediump will only hold 4 of those nybbles, the bottom 0000. That is an overlow. What actually gets put in the uniform at run time there is undefined. It can be max int, min int, 0, anything.

Comment: In any case I just tried it and no luck.

Comment: Well, it is only an overflow if the implementation was lying about the range in the first place, and if one assumes that, no other assumptions from the spec hold either way, so I don't think what you want to do can be done without UB. However, what about uploading both `2<<(range[1] - 1)` and `(float)(2<<(range[1] - 1) )` (which should be exactly representable  as float) as uniforms and compare in shader via `abs(float(int_value)-float_value)<1`

Comment: If the device doesn't support highp in fragment shaders then the value won't fit a mediump float but will fit in a mediump int? But hey, I tried it and it seems to be working! 

Comment: I don't think you will find a real device where (the true) range_int(mediump) > range_float(highests_supported_float_precision).

Comment: If the device is emulating int by floats, then my assumption always holds, and if not, we only need the **logarithm** of the number of integer bits as the number of exponent bits in the float format (with the number of manitssa bits being completely irrelevant). However, what I actually meant was not `2<<x` but `1<<x` of course (I want the highest power of two representable by the integral type, and for 32 bit _signed_ int, range should be 31 and 2^30 would be the value I was interested in)